# Android import sim contacts

Tags: android

We have a custom ROM 4.1,we are finding an issue where contacts of SIM automatically getting imported to Contacts App. I am figuring it out where its happening. I Didnt find this import thing happening in Contacts app. Can anyone help me where this importing stuff would be happening.

many thanks in advance